# iframe inside SVG did not loaded

Tags: html, iframe, svg

As far as I know, Adding HTML tag inside SVG is possible by using `<foreignObject />` tag.
I want to load a page by using iframe inner SVG but it din't work. Am I missing something ? or It just can't possible using HTML inner SVG ?

this is my code :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0">
        <iframe src="content.html" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

I tried to load it directly from browsers, it shows nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

foreignObject elements require width and height attributes. They do not have width and height CSS styles, in fact all of the CSS you're supplying is inappropriate and ignored for a foreignObject element.

This should work (provided you're not using IE as that does not support foreignObject currently)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <iframe src="content.html" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Note that if you move your iframe outside where the foreignObject bounds are using position absolute as you are doing that may also cause problems for you.

Comment: I tried this and it shows a blank screen...

Comment: Ask a new question. Don't forget to provide a [mcve]